# Export products from wp Ecommerce and import into magento

Tags: magento-1.8, import, csv, importexport

What i want to do is export all the existing products from the wordpress e-commerce and have to import it into the magento.I have used ***WP e-Commerce - Store Exporter*** for exporting the data from wordpress. I have exported the data as CSV but if i import into magento its showing error, i know this is because the column names used in wordpress and magento are different and some of the options mismatching also. May i know is there any other options for do this?... I heard about **CART2CART**. But its paid version. Is there any other plugins like that, Also is possible to do it manually?...please give me suggestion for this

Comment: Just use Cart2Cart, it is stupidly cheap and the time saved is impressive. If you can't afford $50-100 or so then you really should not be moving to Magento, your hosting will be that per month for any reasonable site.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Magento's baked-in in dataflow import/export functionality found in adminhtml > system > import/export

If you want a sample export simply set up your attributes/attribute sets to mimic your WP Ecommerce settings -> manually set up a product to reflect the data you have in your exported CSV -> export the product from Magento -> voilá you have a .csv file containing an example product attribute spread and necessary headers.

Magmi will use the same csv formatting as dataflow import/export, and in fact part of their how-to suggests you export a product via dataflow to get a sample import sheet. You should weigh wether or not you need a 3rd party tool like Magmi based on the complexity of the data you need to import, as grappling with Magmi may needlessly complicate your migration.

Answer (score 0):

If you are a developer yourself / comfortable working with code then I would suggest http://sourceforge.net/projects/magmi/ as it's open source and has various plugins for all sorts of Magento things you might end up needing.

The learning curve might be quite high at first but persevere as you can mass edit 1000's of products and their attributes with csvs file as simple as:

```
sku, price, another
1234, 9.99, XXXXXXX
```